# Qt model/View programming and Roles

Tags: c++, qt, model-view

I have been reading articles on Qt's model view programming for a while now however I still am not clear on the concept of roles and what they do in model/view framework. I have been using `QStandardItem` model . Any info regarding this topic would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In a model item can store different types of information and depending on the type you want to access, you provide the role, so you would do this: -

```
model->data(index, role);
```

Where index is the item in the model that you're requesting data for and role is the type of data you want back.

So, for example, if you want to retrieve the standard text that is displayed by an item, then you'd use **Qt::DisplayRole**, whereas to retrieve the tool tip associated with the item, you'd specify the role as the enumeration **Qt::ToolTipRole**.

There are lots of other types, as you can see in the [Qt documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)